# how to use makefile to include .a static library and .h file from another directory in C?

Tags: c++, c, makefile

I have created a `.h` header file, implemented and created `.a` static library file, both of them are in directory in say, `/home/data/folder1`.

I have another `.c` file which will use link the `.h` header file and the `.a` library file. However, the `.c` file is in directory `/home/data/folder2`.

What should I write in the Makefile (which is also located in `/home/data/folder2`)? Also, should I include `myheader.h` in the `.c` file that I want to compile? Here is what I have so far, but not working:

```
LIBB = -L/home/data/folder1/libmylib.a

HEADER = -L/home/data/folder2/myheader.h

main: main.o
    gcc $(HEADER) $(LIBB) $< -o $@

main.o: main.c
    gcc -c main.c

.PHONY: clean

clean:

    rm -f *.o *.~ a.out main
```

Any help will be appreciated, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Including header files and libraries from non-standard directories is simple.

You have the path to the directory *containing* the library and the one containing the header, so we store those in variables:

```
LIBB = /home/data/folder1
LIBINCLUDE = /home/data/folder2
```

Now GCC needs to know where to look for headers, so we simply include it in the `CFLAGS`. The linker (not the compiler) needs to know where to look for libraries, so we can add that to `LDFLAGS`:

```
CFLAGS += -I$(LIBINCLUDE)
LDFLAGS += -L$(LIBB)
```

It will use the `CFLAGS` and `LDFLAGS` automatically if you don't explicitly run GCC.

But for the link step, it needs to know that the library is needed, so:

```
LDFLAGS += -static -lmylib
```

The linker will look for `libmylib.a` in all of the directories named by the `-L` options in `LDFLAGS`.

Since your rules for `main` and `main.o` are explicit, change them like so (but be sure to use a tab, not 4 spaces):

```
main: main.o
    gcc $(LDFLAGS) $< -o $@

main.o: main.c
    gcc $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Comment: Thanks! but uh...what if I have my header and the library in the same directory, while the .c file in another? should I do the same thing? at the mean time, do I have to write #include "myheader.h" in my .c file? Thanks!

Comment: You *may* have to add `-I.` and `-L.`, but the process is all the same. But both of the rules for `main` and `main.o` you can safely leave off the `gcc` line and it'll do the right thing. Also, yes, you *do* need to have an appropriate `#include` directive in your `.c` file.