# Create a stand alone static library with Bazel that uses Tensorflow and openCV?

Tags: c++, opencv, compilation, tensorflow, bazel

I have this project that uses TensorFlow and OpenCV. I installed TF as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620794/how-to-build-and-use-google-tensorflow-c-api) and OpenCV as described [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34984290/building-opencv-code-using-bazel)

I have two pairs of `.cc` and `.h` files that I build using `cc_library` in the `BUILD` file. It compiles and works perfectly. In the `bazel_bin` folder, I noticed that bazel compiled the .a files. I would like to move these files to be elsewhere. However, when I move the folder that held both the binary and the .a files elsewhere I get this error:

> error while loading shared libraries: libopencv_calib3d.so.3.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

How can I fix this?

EDIT1: I am attaching my [BUILD](http://pastebin.com/Ucb9ebmk) file just in case.

EDIT2: So I tried to simply move the .a files to another folder, and link it up (using the method described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19341397/how-to-use-makefile-to-include-a-static-library-and-h-file-from-another-direct)) in the makefile which gives me this error:

> ../src/conversion.h:11:44: fatal error: tensorflow/core/public/session.h: No such file or directory
>   compilation terminated.

Before I thought that my only problem was with OpenCV.

Comment: What is the final binary you are trying to build? Why do you need to copy the bazel built library elsewhere? Can you simply add a rule for the final binary in the `BUILD` file and build it with bazel?

Comment: I am trying to move the .a files as they are needed in another project. That project is already using Makefile and it is a bit late to change it. I was kinda hoping that having a static library could have helped solve a lot of problems.